How to write data to share point list using Azure Data factory
I have a requirment where I need to write data to share point list file using azure data factory , could you please some one help here ?
Is there any way which help to write the data in share point list using data factory .
Thanks,
Vipijn

SharePoint is not supported as sink in ADF so you cannot write data from share point from ADF.


How to write data to share point list using Azure Data factory.


Unfortunately, HTTP is not a supported sink type, also as you can see in the above image SharePoint is not supported as a sink by Azure Data Factory.
You can provide the feedback on the same for adding SharePoint as a sink here.
The workaround can be, you may move a file to SharePoint using Azure Logic Apps. Here his similar SO Threads answer which demostrate moving file to share point using logic app.
